# How to create module in C

Tags: c, object, module, header

I need help with modules in C.

I made a little manager system where I save records about school subjects. I have my `saveToFile` and `readFromFile` functions in one `(main.c)` C file. Now I was asked to create a module for reading and writing functions. I created `SavingFunctions.c` `SavingFunctions.h` and also I was asked to create an object file `.o` but I don't get it if I need to write it to myself or just do nothing, because I see some files with .o in my folder. Also, I use structure, maybe I need to put it in a separate file?

## SavingFunctions.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    #include "SavingFunctions.h"
    
    
    
    
    //READ_FUNCTION
    int numberOfRecords(struct Subjects DataBase[])
    {
    
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
    
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! Failed to open\\find the file. \n");
            exit(1);
        }
    
        int i=0;
    
        //Reads the contents of a structure variable from file
        while(fread(&DataBase[i], sizeof(DataBase[i]),1, fp) == 1)
        {
            ++i;
        }
    
        fclose(fp);
    
        return i;
    
    }
    
    
    
    //WRITE_FUNCTION
    void writeTofile(struct Subjects DataBase[], int positionToWrite)
    {
        int recordsNumber;
    
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb");
    
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! Failed to open or find the file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    
        recordsNumber = 0;
    
        for(int i=0; i<=positionToWrite;++i)
        {
            fwrite(&DataBase[i], sizeof(Subjects), 1, fp);
            recordsNumber++;
        }
    
        fclose(fp);
    
        printf("Total number of items in the file: %d\n", recordsNumber);
    
    }
```

## SavingFunctions.h

```
    typedef struct Subjects
    {
        char Lesson[20];
        char TeachersName[20];
        char TeachersLastName[20];
        int Credits;
        int NumberOfStudents;
    } Subjects;
    
    #ifndef SAVINGFUNCTIONS_H
    #define SAVINGFUNCTIONS_H
    
    
    
    int numberOfRecords(struct Subjects DataBase[]);
    void writeTofile(struct Subjects DataBase[], int positionToWrite);
    
    #endif
```

Comment: The structure should be defined inside the `#ifndef` / `#endif` block (after the `#define` line).  Usually, `file.c` and `file.h` are a pair — use the same filename prefix for both unless the header declares material defined in several different source files.

Comment: You 'accept' changes by leaving them unedited — there's no need for further action.  Try to make sure you are editing the current version, but that can sometimes be difficult if several people are editing the question at the same time.  FYI, I tend to use `###` markers for sub-headings; the single `#` headings are more emphatic than I like.  That is, however, a matter of taste.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but if I put structure into SavingFunctions.h between #ifndef / #endif  and also put into main.c I get an error. What could be a problem?

Comment: Don't do that — don't define the structure in several different places.  Include the header where the structure is needed.  DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `.o` files are called object files. If you compile a source file with gcc (without the option `-o`), an object file with the extension `.o` will be created at the same location of the source file. To give the object file a specific name, you have to specify the `-o` option, like:

```
gcc -c -o module_name SavingFunctions.c
```

Like noted in the comment section below, you don't have a main function. Therefore you have to add a -c option (for compile). Afterwards you can link the object files together to create a library or an executable (with a main function). Or use the other methods which are mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: Since there is no `main()` function in the module (and there shouldn't be one), there will need to be at least two object files (or source files, or a mix of source and object files) listed on the (compiling and) linking command line.  Or the module will need to be put into a library and then the program linked with that library.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to worry about `.o` files. It is a compiled file ready to be linked by the linker into the executable file.

Simple run gcc with all the `.c` files listed in the command line.

`$ gcc -Wall main.c SavingFunctions.c -o executable_name` where the `executable_name` is the name of the created program and 'main.c' is the source file containing the the `main` function definition.

then run the program `./executable_name`.

The guards should protect the whole .h file so your one should be

```
    #ifndef SAVINGFUNCTIONS_H
    #define SAVINGFUNCTIONS_H
     
    typedef struct Subjects
    {
        char Lesson[20];
        char TeachersName[20];
        char TeachersLastName[20];
        int Credits;
        int NumberOfStudents;
    } Subjects;
    
    int numberOfRecords(struct Subjects DataBase[]);
    void writeTofile(struct Subjects DataBase[], int positionToWrite);
    
    #endif
```